# How could I fix my code, so that only a word's position is found and not the word which contains a character when a character is inputted?

Tags: python

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence excluding punctuation")



chars = set('0123456789!"£$%^&*()_-+={}[];:@#~/?.,<>\|`¬')
while any((c in chars) for c in sentence):
    sentence = input("Please enter another sentence excluding punctuation")
else:
    print('Your sentence is fine')
sentence = sentence.upper()

locateword = input ("Enter a word from the inputted sentence to locate")
locateword=locateword.upper()


while locateword not in sentence:

    locateword = input ("Enter another word from the inputted sentence to locate")
    locateword=locateword.upper()
else:
    print ("Your word is fine")

sentence = sentence.split()

for (position,words) in enumerate(sentence):
    if (locateword in words):
        print ("The position of your word is",position+1)
```

> > > This code finds the position of an inputted word in the inputted sentence. However when a single character is the word to be located, the code finds the position of the word that contains that character, how could I fix this code so that this doesn't happen? For example, when the sentence is "I like football" and the word is "ball", the position returned is 3 as "ball" is found in "football", but I do not want this to happen.

Comment: Do you want it to find that word regardless of the either it's in upper or lower case? That's what the  `upper()` is for?

Comment: if possible could the whole code be typed out as solutions are confusing as to where they should be placed in the code

Comment: the word and sentence are put to upper case to so that the code isn't case sensitive. so the user can input in any case

Comment: Please check if my answer works, is it want you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if locateword in sentence:
    print(sentence.index(locateword)+1)
```

Use this before you split your sentence.

OR,

```
import re
index = re.search(r'\b'+locateword+r'\b', sentence)
if index:
    print(index.start())
    print(index.end())
else:
    print("Word not in sentence")
```

Do this before you split your sentence again.

The `\b` is meant for word boundaries in regex. So it wouldn't catch a word within a word.

Comment: this then returns no position and the outcome is still the same

Comment: I've edited the answer. You just need the position of the word inside the sentence, right?

Comment: `print(sentence.index(locateword)+1)` to be exact.

Comment: I need the position(s) of the word in the sentence. the edited answer still has the same outcome but then prints another number.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your output should look like?

Comment: Each word in the sentence should have a positional number, then when a word that is in the sentence is inputted, the position of that word should be printed. Using index simply says when the inputted word occurs in the sentence and not where.

Comment: for example,   when "i like football" is the sentence and the word is "ball". "ball" shouldn't be accepted as it isn't a word in the sentence.

Comment: add the import to the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, because `sentence` has already been split, so `if (locateword in words)` will search `ball` in `football` instead of searching in `["I", "like", "football"]`

You could try:

```
sentence = "I like to kick the ball"
words = sentence.split()
word = "ball"
if word in words:
    print words.index(word)+1
else: 
    print (word, 'is not in the inputted sentence')
```

Comment: but the code should allow any word and sentence not just one example

Comment: @User123 This answer is just an example. Just replace `sentence= ...` by `sentence=input('your sentence:')` and so the variable `word`. Adapt it to fit your need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
for (position,words) in enumerate(sentence):
    if (upper(locateword) == upper(words)): #case insensitive
        print ("The position of your word is",position+1)
```

Altough that wasn't your question, a better way to check if a string has alphanumerical characters is:

```
import re
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence excluding punctuation")
if re.search(r"\W", sentence):
    sentence = input("Please enter another sentence excluding punctuation")
else: print("Your sentence is ok!")
```

Full code:

```
import re
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence excluding punctuation: ")
while( re.search(r"\W ", sentence)):
    sentence = input("Please enter another sentence excluding punctuation: ")
print("Your sentence is ok!")

sentence = sentence.split(" ")

locateword = input("Enter a word: ")
while(locateword.lower() not in [x.lower() for x in sentence]):
    locateword = input("Enter another word: ")

for (position,words) in enumerate(sentence):
    if (locateword.upper() == words.upper()): #case
        print ("The position of your word is",position+1)
```

Comment: this doesn't fulfil what i wish to do as if the sentence does contain punctuation, the program just ends. also the code ends if the word isn't in the sentence. these should be loops so that while the sentence includes punctuation, the user should keep being asked to input another sentence.

Comment: @User123 Edited it